# Why do I have to hard reset my Nanostation to reconnect to management radio?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

We have a pair of ubiquiti Nanostation ac5 units we wish to set up as a PtP bridge.

We're having problems and the worst is that when the management radio turns off after 15 minutes, we cannot reconnect to it. The instruction packet says we should simply power cycle the unit but although the WiFi reappears when we do this, we cannot connect to it successfully (on Windows laptop, Android phone or iPhone). If we hard reset the unit we then *can* connect to the management WiFi again but all our settings are gone so we just go round in circles, we get 15 minutes to setup from scratch!

Comment: Since you have a laptop – have you considered configuring the NS through a wired Ethernet connection?

Comment: I only realised this was an option later but I still wish I knew... I think it must be a DHCP issue

Comment: You can SSH into the device and check whether the DHCP server is running, whether it's receiving packets from the client devices, etc.